# So close to my first build! Ethernet connected but no internet, 17.04, Intel I217-V, Driver: e1000e

Tags: drivers, internet, 17.04, ethernet, intel

First time poster and first time PC builder so happy to elaborate on anything as required.

I've just built a new PC.  Both Ethernet and Wireless doesn't work either would be fine for me!

Ethernet:

`lshw -C network` gives:

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (5) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 00
   serial: 2c:4d:54:ec:d8:9a
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=192.168.192.28 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:140 memory:df300000-df31ffff
```

`ip l` gives

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 2c:4d:54:ec:d8:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`/etc/network/interfaces` gives

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`ping -c3 8.8.8.8` gives

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=16.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=14.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=18.0 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.008/16.148/18.009/1.651 ms
```

`route -n` gives

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.192.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s31f6
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s31f6
192.168.192.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s31f6
```

`tracepath 8.8.8.8` gives

```
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  Deep-Genesis                                        648.751ms !H
 1:  no reply
 1:  Deep-Genesis                                        3067.668ms !H
 Resume: pmtu 1500
```

`tracepath 151.101.129.69` gives

```
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  Deep-Genesis                                        1426.341ms !H
 Resume: pmtu 1500
```

The wireless adapter doesn't get recognized at all!

Please help! I'm sooooo close!

Comment: Your ethernet clearly shows an IP address suggesting that it is connected. Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `route -n` and also: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks @chili555 for such a quick response. Please see mine above. Wonderful community this is.

Comment: Ethernet is working.

Comment: I'd love to agree with you @Pilot6. Unfortunately, my web browser doesn't. I don't know what I'm missing but it is frustrating.

I can see there is data but I cannot use anything that requires the internet on that computer.

Comment: What if you enter `151.101.129.69` in your browser address bar?

Comment: I get the following error @Pilot6:

Fastly error: unknown domain: 151.101.129.69. Please check that this domain has been added to a service.

Comment: Please add output of `tracepath 8.8.8.8` and `tracepath 151.101.129.69` to your question.

Comment: And how are you connected to the internet?

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6. I've added this to the question. I'm connected via wireless on another laptop and my phone. I can use the wired connection with my laptop with no issues - just not on my new computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please click the Network Manager icon and select Edit Connections. Under IPv4 settings, enter DNS nameservers like this:

[image]

Restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Test:

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Here is the breakdown. It's still not working

'ping -c3 8.8.8.8' gives

    PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
    From 192.168.192.28 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2029ms
pipe 3


`ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com`

    ping: www.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known

Comment: Is this a router issue? Is the problem solved, even temporarily, if you power-cycle the router? May we see: `grep -e enp -e etwork /var/log/syslog` As the result will be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Also paste: `grep -i dns /var/log/syslog`

Comment: Thanks @chili555 for the persistence. Here is the link you are after: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25486890/. A power-cycle unfortunately has no effect.

Comment: Please wait - my router now has an issue! I will let you know when it's been resolved and if my internet now works.

Comment: Solved! Your solution absolutely worked but my internet went down at exactly the same time. Now it's all done. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working as expected.